# Sharing files from a computer connected to a repeater to the rest of the network

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, workgroup

This is a simple problem I have. I want to easily share files between Windows 10 machines on the same network, using Windows Workgroup system. I have configured my router to be a repeater so I could connect from my phone to the same Wi-fi network in another part of my home. And also to be able to connect to the rest of the computers. My PC is connected to that router which acts as a repeater which is in turn connected to the main internet (router) hub.

Problem is the network sharing tab doesn't detect any other machine. On the advanced sharing options both the PCs have everything turned on.

I would have posted the router settings screen but I can't post images here.

My IP: 192.168.0.x

Other PC: 192.168.1.x

I will appreciate any help, I'm new to networking so I'm not really sure what should be doing :)

EDIT: Router was in bridge mode because of a tutorial I watched and I thought it's the same as repeater mode.

Comment: With different IP ranges it's not working as a repeater but as a bridge.

Comment: Then I guess the video walkthrough that I watched is wrong. In the Network->LAN section of the router I can change the IP so I guess I need to match it as 192.168.1.1?

Comment: Not exactly. The router doing the repetition should be configured explicitly as a "repeater", not as a second network, i.e., only the main one should be a DHCP server, etc. A bridge mode also works both for internet access and network (file, printers, ...) shares but requires additional configurations (i know nothing about that) whereas with a true repeater mode everything works as if connected to the same router.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess the router I'm using TP-WR741ND is pretty old cause I don't see any option for anything that explicitly says repeater and the spec page doesn't have it. Is there any workaround (besides buying another router) that doesn't require much trickery?

Comment: Sorry, you're asking the wrong person. I  know very little about it.

Comment: Would you be comfortable flashing this router to third party firmware?

Comment: Depends if I can rollback if something bad happens, I don't really have this problem anymore because I kinda gave up and just connected my PC to the modem where I can talk to the rest of the network and the router works like a bridge (couldn't make it work like a repeater instead).